# Flex mobile black screen after an android popup opened when a camera was attached

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, video, camera

I found an issue where the app shows a black screen after showing an android popup e.g. "System update" or "Select a mail app" what is caused by the camera object.

After a camera is attached to the video and a popup is opened (any time later):

includes pseudo code

```
video = new Video(width, height); //flash.media.Video
video.attachCamera(camera); //flash.media.Camera
videoContainer.addChild(video);

...

<s:Button label="send mail" click="{clear() and navigateToURL('mailTo:...');}"/> //will cause to open the "Select a mail app"-popup

function clear()
{
     video.attachCamera(null);
     video.clear();
     removeChild(video);
     video = null;
     camera = null;
}
```

When the black screen is shown the flex app is still active and other buttons are clickable (if you find them). It seem's like it just doesn't render the flex app again but this issue doesn't occur if the camera was not attached previously. Also it doesn't matter which view of the navigator view stack is active. If the the camera was attached once the black screen will be shown on any view at any time later after the popup opened.

So I would like to know if there is a way to force the app to render the current view again or if there are some further methods to clear/delete/erase the camera object from memory.

@edit

my video object is added to a SpriteVisualElement

```
<s:SpriteVisualElement id="videoContainer"/>
```

@edit

After further investigation it seems that the renderMode auto, gpu, cpu, direct also affects the bahavior. Some times the black screen is visible for a short time and the view renders then again, with another mode it shows the view for a short time and then the black screen, ... In my case described above it's set to 'gpu'.